# Eclipse run error

Tags: eclipse

When i try to run my code on Eclipse this error appears:

```
Usage: javaw [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  javaw [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
    -d32      use a 32-bit data model if available
    -d64      use a 64-bit data model if available
    -server   to select the "server" VM
    -hotspot      is a synonym for the "server" VM  [deprecated]
                  The default VM is server.
```

`-cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
-classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
              A ; separated list of directories, JAR archives,
              and ZIP archives to search for class files.
-D<name>=<value>
              set a system property
-verbose:[class|gc|jni]
              enable verbose output
-version      print product version and exit
-version:<value>
              require the specified version to run
-showversion  print product version and continue
-jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
              include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
-? -help      print this help message
-X            print help on non-standard options
-ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
-enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
              enable assertions with specified granularity
-da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
-disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
              disable assertions with specified granularity
-esa | -enablesystemassertions
              enable system assertions
-dsa | -disablesystemassertions
              disable system assertions
-agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
              load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
              see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
-agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
              load native agent library by full pathname
-javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
              load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument
-splash:<imagepath>
              show splash screen with specified image
 See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for more details.`

i try to coment my entired code and this error still appear.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you haven't set your java path correctly.

[Setting Up Eclipse with Java 1.6 on Windows](http://www.ugrad.cs.ubc.ca/~cs211/tutorials/Eclipse/Eclipse_Java_Windows_XP.html)

[How To Install and Get Started with Java Programming](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/EclipseJava_HowTo.html)

Comment: but i can run others projects, just this on that i can't. And they belong to the same repository.

Comment: Can you run a new java project?

Comment: Yes, that indicate you don't set your java environment right. Pls set it up.

Comment: the same problem occur again but now the comands: java -version and javac -version are working

Answer (score 0):

Run eclipse in clean mode

Edit the eclipse.ini file located in your Eclipse install directory and insert -clean as the first line.

Answer (score 0):

If this is happening to a specific project only and other projects are running fine then your default run configuration might have changed. You may try the following 
- Run -> Run As -> 1 Java Application.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed this issue by deleting some of my old runtime configurations.  Eclipse then started automatically generating them again.