# Invalid command do javaw in Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, javaw

Sorry for the ambiguous title, but I've literally no idea how to even name this behavior. When I try to compile any project in Eclipse, I get this in the console:

```
Usage: javaw [-options] class [args...]
       (to execute a class)
   or  javaw [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
       (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
-d32      use a 32-bit data model if available
-d64      use a 64-bit data model if available
-server   to select the "server" VM
-hotspot      is a synonym for the "server" VM  [deprecated]
              The default VM is server.

-cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
-classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
              A ; separated list of directories, JAR archives,
              and ZIP archives to search for class files.
-D<name>=<value>
              set a system property
-verbose[:class|gc|jni]
              enable verbose output
-version      print product version and exit
-version:<value>
              require the specified version to run
-showversion  print product version and continue
-jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
              include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
-? -help      print this help message
-X            print help on non-standard options
-ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
-enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
              enable assertions with specified granularity
-da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
-disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
              disable assertions with specified granularity
-esa | -enablesystemassertions
              enable system assertions
-dsa | -disablesystemassertions
              disable system assertions
-agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
              load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
              see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
-agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
              load native agent library by full pathname
-javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
              load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument
-splash:<imagepath>
              show splash screen with specified image
See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for more details.
```

And it stops. What the hell is that?

Comment: Seems you are using an incorrect command or arguments. Edit the question with the exact commandline you are using

Comment: may be duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14993683/eclipse-run-error or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9862037/trouble-compiling-any-java-code-in-eclipse

Comment: okay, I changed the run configuration and it works, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[eclipse](/questions/tagged/eclipse) is issuing an invalid command to [javaw](/questions/tagged/javaw).

Run the code in debug mode right click on the process item in the "Debug" view and choose "Properties".  You should see the command it is using, you'll be able to see what's wrong from there.